# Updating mysql records from Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm just diving into Laravel this week. I've done a few tutorials and have been able to figure out how to setup my database, loop through my records and display them in a view. With each record I am displaying a checkbox and each is set to `checked="checked"` based on a boolean field from the "CheckedIn column in the database. I want to be able to uncheck multiple records then submit and update that column in the database then refresh the page showing the changed records as unchecked. Just looking for a jumping off point or links to resources that explain this process better. If I could figure out how to do it via javascript and AJAX that'd be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post up more information for people to help you.

Your process would be something like this:

Create the table with a form, with all the checkboxes named with the ID of the row in the DB table

->

Submit the form

->

Get all the inputs for the checked boxes

->

loop through and see whether it is checked or not

->

Update that row in the database

->

Redirect back